# Netbeans out of memory exception

Tags: jvm, netbeans-7, heap-memory, ubuntu-13.04

Netbeans out of memory exception

I increased the -Xmx value in netbeans file.
but the IDE is busy acquiring more memory to scan projects ?
the memory usage increases and the process is slow, and non responsive

Comment: Your Question's title is incorrect.  Your problem is clearly NOT an OOME.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your system is thrashing.  The heap size is now so large that there is not enough physical memory on your system to hold it ... and all of the other things you are running.

The end result is that your system has to copy memory pages between physical memory and the disc page file.  Too much of that and the system performance will drop dramatically.  You will see that the disc activity light is "on" continually.  (The behaviour is worst during Java garbage collection, because that entails accessing lots of VM pages in essentially random order.)

If this is your problem then there is no easy solution:

- You could reduce the `-Xmx` a bit ...
- You could stop other applications running; e.g. quit your web browser, email client, etc.
- You could buy more memory.  (This only works up to a point ... if you are using a 32bit system / 32bit OS / 32bit JVM.)
- You could switch to a less memory-hungry operating system or distro.

Comment: I have 8 GB memory, I increased the heap size using -Xmx to be able to run the IDE without porblems, I'm not running out of memory but the IDE takes a lot of time to respond

Comment: If you have projects open unnecessarily, close some of them.